# Swapping Shalom Rav for Sim Shalom Intentionally

Tags: halacha, tefilla

On all days, one says Sim Shalom by Shacharis and Shalom Rav by Maariv, and by Mincha, one usually says Shalom Rav, except for fast days. (At least according to Nusach Ashkenaz, a topic discussed [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15631/9682), [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10426/9682), and [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/69476/9682).)

[Here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/65216/9682), the discussion is what if someone accidentally switched them. What if one switched them on purpose?

Comment: Why would on purpose be different??

Comment: @DoubleAA Perhaps it's only okay bedieved, but not lechatchilah.

Comment: Of course it's not ok lechatchilah. Lechatchila you follow the Nusach. That's not what you are asking about. (Though note some Nuschaot have Sim Shalom always and others have Shalom Rav always.)

Comment: Even if you skip half the words on purpose you're Yotzei http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/15925/759 How could this be worse?

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't think it is. Want to post that as an answer?

Comment: this is the same chatima so equivalent beracha

Comment: @kouty By that logic I could swap out Sukkos davening for Pesach davening because both conclude with mekadeish Yisrael vehazemanim.

Comment: @DonielF "I could swap out Sukkos davening for Pesach " I think you're getting carried away, a bit. Shalosh Refalim davening is absolutely identical in all ways except for the Torah reading, a paragraph in Musaph, and the holiday mentioned in 2 other paragraphs (difference of about 3 words.) Overall, there's not much swapping to do ;-)

Comment: shalom rav for chachme provenza were on 3 tefilot. exactly equivalent. sucot is a mention of one event . ahavat olam & ahava raba is also the same

Comment: @DanF Sure, but I'm talking about entirely the wrong holiday. "On this day of Sukkos, the time of our joy." But...it's Pesach...

Comment: @DonielF Who knew Art Scroll could ever be mistaken??? I saw this type of error in one edition of the Art Scroll Pesach Machzor. It mentioned Succot. Well, at least got the simcha part correct :-)